# Obtaining a logical line of code

Tags: clang, llvm-clang

How do I get logical lines of code using Clang ?
For instance in this code fragment:

```
int main()
{
int x = 10;
printf("%d",
x);
return 0;
}
```

When I traverse the code as Stmts, I get the Stmts as:

- printf("%d",
- x);

How do I consolidate them into one Stmt or how I read the source code as lines of code that are not limited by new lines ?

Comment: Please include your current code in the question.

Comment: Can you show the code where you "traverse the code as Stmts" and get that output? The clang API generally shouldn't care about newlines at all.